# How to pop-up an image from array list /javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a page that displays my items from an array list, and each of them have an image, that is capped to `120px`. What would be the way to pop up that image in the middle of the sreen with bigger size. I have seen some plugins that can help with that, but I wanna do it without any plugins.

html:

```
<div id="animallist"></div>
```

javascript:

```
const animals = [{
    name: "Cat",
    useful: "no",
    image: "https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Dog",
    useful: "yes",
    image: "https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Fish",
    useful: "no",
    image: "https://cdn0.wideopenpets.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Fish-Names-770x405.png"
  },
  ]

animals.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(animal, i) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const animalList = document.createElement('h2');
  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.id = "image";
  animalList.innerHTML =  animal.name + " " +"-"+"useful?" + " "+ animal.useful;
  animalList.style.cssText = "text-align:center;"
  image.src = animal.image;
  div.appendChild(image);
  div.appendChild(animalList);
  div.dataset.animalName = animal.name;
  animallist.appendChild(div);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7y3qgm5s/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create 'pop-up' div with 'display: none' class in the beginning, then with JS remove that 'display: none' class and change inner img src to your img. Here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/bcdu3L2j/1/

```
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
const imgsArray = Array.from(imgs);

const popUp = document.getElementById('pop-up');
const popImg = document.querySelector('#pop-up img');

function popUpImage(e) {
  const imgSrc = e.target.src;
  popImg.src = imgSrc;
  popUp.classList.remove("hidden");
}

imgsArray.forEach((img) => {
 img.addEventListener('click', popUpImage);
})
popUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popUp.classList.add("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Could you look at it? https://jsfiddle.net/9nvgbayz/5/ . I have a problem with a class, I wanted to highlight the image on hover, but the class with highlighter was supposed be removed when clicked on image and then added again. I tried to do it, but no luck. I am not really sure how to remove class only from the image that I have clicked and not from all the images.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do, but if you have problem with img you clicked overlapping the pop-up you should just add z-index on the pop-up css, do not remove and add class for that, its unnecessary. https://jsfiddle.net/jtu312hf/7/